# Почему не определяется объект Promise?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise

Почему вычисляемое свойство,полученное из Промиса, выдает [object Promise] на самой странице, хотя в консоли 14 (как и должно быть):

```
<div id="content">
  <div v-if="allNewsList">{{allNewsList}}</li>
</div>
<script>
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#content',
    computed: {
      async allNewsList() {
        let data = await axios.get('http://news/filtered_news/author_all/period_all').then(response => {return response.data});
        console.log(data.length);
        return data.length;
      },
    }
 });
```

Comment: 1. поясните код: `await axios.get()`. Потому, что промис не сразу выполняется. У вас запрос может и 30 секунд выполняться.

Comment: @ObehanProger, метод `then` вам и возвращает Promise. Вы уже написали ключевое слово `await`, зачем вам еще и коллбэк функция? 
`let data = await axios.get(...);`

Comment: Я убрал then. Проблема сохраняется. Теперь в консоли undefined

Comment: @ObehanProger, `await axios.get();` возвращает объект, у которого нет свойства `length`, отсюда `undefined`. 
`let response = await axios.get(...); 
console.log(response.data)`;

Comment: Исправил: все также как изначально. В консоли 14, а на странице [object Promise]

Comment: @ObehanProger, ваше вычисляемое свойство `allNewsList` это асинхронная функция, вот она и возвращает вам Promise и выводит на страницу. В вашем случае вычисляемое свойство не нужно. Создайте метод в котором получаете данные и записывайте их в реактивное свойство.

Comment: А почему тогда в консоль выводит а на страницу нет?

Comment: а с чего вы взяли, что `computed` может быть асинхронным? В консоли все ок, потому что вы дожидаетесь выполнения через `await`, но само св-во `computed` вызывается как есть, без `await`, поэтому и оно возвращает промис

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все верно по поводу asyncСomputed, а вот как вариант если сделать просто по create.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#content',
  data: {
    allNewsList: null
  },
  created() {
    this.$http.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.status == "200") {
          this.allNewsList = response.headers.map['content-length'][0];
        }
      })
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-resource@1.3.4"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div v-if="allNewsList">{{ allNewsList }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало! Вся фишка в created? И что за vue-resource плагин?

Comment: По сути просто выполняется при создании, но ответ thisMan абсолютно правилен так же. А vue-resource для исполнения запроса в данном примере в нем зашит http.get

Answer (score 2):

Сами по себе св-ва в `computed` будут вызваться как обычные функции. Грубо говоря

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#content',
    computed: {
      async data() {
        let data = await asyncOperation();
        return data.length;
      },
    }
 });

 // Где-то в коде vue будет вызвано просто
 computed.data();
 // next code...
```

Становится понятно, что никто не дожидается выполнения асинхронной функции, поэтому она и возвращает `Promise<value>`, которое используется, как значение.

> хотя в консоли 14 (как и должно быть):

Потому уже внутри функции вы дожидаетесь выполнения асинхронной функции. А значит и вернет она уже значение, а не `Promise`

Что делать? Использовать плагин: [vue-async-computed](https://github.com/foxbenjaminfox/vue-async-computed)

Вот пример из документации:

```
new Vue({
  data: {
    userId: 1
  },
  asyncComputed: {
    username () {
      return Vue.http.get('/get-username-by-id/' + this.userId)
        .then(response => response.data.username)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Не согласен. Почему тогда сам объект распечатывается на странице путем перебора v-for="newsItem in allNewsList", а вот именно его длину почему-то нельзя определить?

Comment: Какой объект? `allNewsList` возвращает промис, `axios.get с await` возвращает значение. вы уберите `await` у `axios` и получите такое же поведение как и у `allNewsList`

Comment: у вас `allNewsList` вызывается без `await` в этом проблема, эту проблему решает плагин, который я указал в ответе

Comment: _распечатывается на странице путем перебора v-for="newsItem in allNewsList"_ вы из функции возвращаете число, а не массив, где это у вас в вопросе? Как вы получаете данные объекта? Методом? Таким же`computed` cв-вом?

Comment: если для каждой мелочи использовать плагин, страница будет долго грузиться

Comment: еще раз `computed` св-ва должны быть __синхронными__, если нужно асинхронно, подключите плагин

Comment: Попробовал через CDN подключить, по ходу не подключается. Выдает в консоли Error in getter for watcher "_async_computed$allNewsList": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение, я все понял в чем причина, но решение ниже сработало сейчас и я его отметил как верное решение